# adding productFlavors in build.grade(Module:app) giving error

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-productflavors

i am adding in build.gradle(Module:app) the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sis.newpro"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

productFlavors {
    prod {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'URL', '"http://api.abcd.com"'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

}
```

giving   Error:(22, 0) Could not find method productFlavors() for arguments [build_bqh9qnip9k7nqy2kbpova0vtq$_run_closure2@5b30b3a7] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

do i missing any thing to add in build.gradle(Module:app) or do i need to add any thing to build.gradle(Project:NewProject)

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: Did you add productFlavor in module level gradle?

Comment: yes added and the build.gradle file also added here

Comment: do you make dir " prod " in "src/" folder?

Comment: not added the dir prod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `productFlavors` tag inside the `android` braces, it needs to be a sibling of `buildTypes`.

---

Your **build.gradle** would end up being something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sis.newpro"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        testInstrumentationRunner
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'URL', '"http://api.abcd.com"'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Follow below steps to create build flavour :**

```
productFlavors {

TestFlavourType {
                applicationId "com.test.flavour"
                minSdkVersion 17
                targetSdkVersion 25
                versionCode 3
                versionName "1.02"
                multiDexEnabled true
                }
```

**Defining Source Sets to pick from different folders:**

```
sourceSets {
        main { //Main
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' - picks from Main
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
```

**If you want to maintain different layout/styles/String u need to define as follows :**

```
TestFlavourType {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/TestFlavourType/res-TestFlavourType', 'src/CommonLayoutDir/res']
            // For resources it will look for the files in this path [src/TestFlavourType/res-TestFlavourType] else it will look in to this [src/CommonLayoutDir/res]
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/TestFlavourType/assets', 'src/main/assets']
        }       
}       

}//productFlavors end
```

Under Src directory create a folder to Maintain separate layout files for different flavors.Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: thank you for ur valuable comment but i will try it later.